# Model Imported. But still company.save() not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm using .find to locate the right company and then adding values to it.....did a console.log(company)is working properly.

But when trying to save it....I get company.save() is not a function. I'm new to mongoose and programming. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
const { Company } = require('../models/company');

 const company = await Company.find({
                userAdmin: `${data.object.metadata.userId}`
            });

            company[0].customerId = data.object.customer;
            company[0].postNumber = data.object.metadata.postNumber;
            company[0].accountStatus = data.object.metadata.accountStatus;

            try {
                await company.save();
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex.message);
                for (field in ex.errors) console.log(ex.errors[field].message);
            }
```

Comment: It would have been great if you could share the error msg also. 
However, as @nathan-wiles answered, you need to use findOne instead of find.
Also, it's safer to check first, if company actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause I company have multiple document in it . And you just modify one and save one too so you should try
`company[0].save()`

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped me troubleshoot. company[0].save() solved my issue.

Comment: Hope you can mark this as a solution ^^

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` on a mongoose model returns an array of documents, not just one.

An array won't have the `.find()` funtion on it; only the documents themselves inside it will.

If you're only looking for a single document, use [.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead.